# How do you prevent spaces while pasting text into input field?

Tags: jquery

How to prevent spaces from being pasted into an input field?

For example: I have two different `input` fields for first name and last name. I have disabled spaces from being *typed* into the input fields by using a simple jQuery, nevertheless, it seems that if I copied and pasted 'Tom Riddle' into either one of the input fields, the space between 'Tom' and 'Riddle' gets pasted into the input field as well.
edit: As a first name of a person or a last name of a person will not contain any spaces, I need to disable.

This is the `jQuery` which I use for disabling spaces from being *typed* :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.no_space').keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which === 32) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can I suggest *not* trying to do this? Some names have spaces in them. (Some names also have various other non-alphabetic characters in them. Those of us with those names get *really cheesed off* at sites that prevent our spelling our names correctly.)

Comment: Sometimes you just have to trust the user. Don't try to help the user how to spell there own name. Maybe give a small hint about errors but don't try to over validate.

Comment: This question is fine, and has other applications besides the OP's original use case. For example, I want to prevent pasting of spaces into an email address field, which should never have spaces for any reason.

Answer (score 10):

Bind the [input event](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#event-input-input) and replace the presence of spaces. For modern browsers, this covers both typing and pasting on an input field.

```
$('.no_space').on("input", function () {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/ /g, ""));
});
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gmz7U/1/).